# Border radius in ie9 producing clear lines in element (image linked for reference)

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I'm using css to create a button style with anchor tags (css below), and the code works in firefox, safari, and chrome just fine with the rounded corners showing perfectly. In ie9 though, there is a strange banding that is occurring inside of the button. I've attached an image to show what I mean, there are these lines that go about half way through the button. It's really weird, and it even shows up on the buttons in a tutorial I found while trying figure out if it was just me. Here's the link to the tutorial: http://pythoughts.com/pure-css-buttons/

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? The lines are actually transparent, as you can see the yellow background of the middle div through the lines in the button. I'm at a loss here for how to correct this.

css:

```
.button{
    padding:1px 5px;
    background:#cbebd3;
    color:#333;
    border:1px solid #98b99e;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I'm using the style like so:

```
<a href="some-link.php" class="button">View Details</a>
```

Here's the image:

[image: Button Issue]

As per a suggestion below, I tried out the code in jsfiddle, and got the same results. Shown below.
[image: issue in jsfiddle]

Comment: I cannot see the problem in the link you provided. Can you please post a http://jsfiddle.net recreating your specific example?

Comment: I'm still getting the same results in jsfiddle, I'll attach the screen shot to the post.

Comment: It works perfectly for me in Windows 7 - IE9. No colour banding.

Comment: I had another friend tell me that it was working on his pc too. I'm at a complete loss as to why this would be occurring for just my browser. Thanks for checking it out on your end.

Comment: I confirm that Win 7 IE9 (version 9.0.8112.16421) looked fine for me too. It could be for you: 1) different version of IE9? 2) different version of Windows? 3) a video card problem? Those are the only things I can think of.

Comment: Do you have any Add-Ons for IE installed? Like ad blocker? Think of any unusual software =)

Comment: @ScottS I forgot to mention that widows 7 is running in a vm. Google Chrome for windows shows the pages fine, I'm only seeing the issue in IE9. It's a fresh install of windows 7, no add ons. This issue has only occurred for border-radius. I'd have to check my version number, but my friend who isn't having the issue on his pc had the same version as me.

Comment: Are you zooming the page? I've had these types of problems in all kinds of browsers before when I've zoomed.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus No, the page wasn't zoomed in. I'm ready to chalk this up to windows voodoo and remove the vm and reinstall then run updates and try again. I've googled quite a bit, and can not find anyone else who has had this issue.

Comment: I can also confirm that it works fine on my Win7 system w/IE 9 installed. Your VM may be causing an issue with repainting messages and minor differences in UI scaling / zoom translation. Do the bands appear / disappear more when you zoom?

Comment: I can confirm that this IS happening to me in IE9 (9.0.8112.16421) when running in Windows 7 (Ultimate) WITHIN a VM. I am using VMWare Fusion 3.1.4 inside of OSX 10.6.8. In fact, I get glitchiness in IE9 on all pages that employ border-radius. The only common thread seems to be the fact that IE9 is running within a VM! With that in mind, the only audience affected should be those running IE9 inside of Windows inside of a VM.

Answer (score 0):

In my IE9 (win 7) also works great, i can only give you one advice, you dont have to add prefixes for border-radius, box-shadow and text-shadow any more,
border-radius 
box-shadow 
text-shadow
(maybe more things)
are now standard for all latest browsers

Comment: It is seldom safe to support only "latest browsers" - esp. when the issue he is specifically mentioning is an IE related one. Though in general, leaving out mozilla and webkit prefixes because they've implemented is safe(er) - because they update more aggressively.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `display: block;` or `float: left;` otherwise a tag is inline

Comment: The button class I made is meant to be versatile, and to be used inline if need be. Regardless, that doesn't cause the transparent banding in the background color.